# MongoDB Return the count of documents for each day for the last one month

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

I have a collection with documents updating everyday. Can someone provide me some suggestion for returning the count of the documents added on every day for the last one month.
I am having a field with created time stamp as shown here ..
"createdTimestamp" : ISODate("2014-03-19T19:25:23.351Z")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) to achieve what you want:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Get only records created in the last 30 days
    {$match:{
          "createdTimestamp":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)}
    }}, 
    // Get the year, month and day from the createdTimeStamp
    {$project:{
          "year":{$year:"$createdTimestamp"}, 
          "month":{$month:"$createdTimestamp"}, 
          "day": {$dayOfMonth:"$createdTimestamp"}
    }}, 
    // Group by year, month and day and get the count
    {$group:{
          _id:{year:"$year", month:"$month", day:"$day"}, 
          "count":{$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Anand works great for me !!!!
Is there a way that in my collection the createdTimeStamp is in GMT I need this in EST time stamps ...

Comment: No problem.  StackOverflow's recommended practice is to post a new question since it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: Is it possible to get it like

Date             count
2014/03/20        5
2014/03/19        10
2014/03/15        15

Ryt now we are getting them in the array format which I can't view in table format ...

Comment: Look at [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/), since you already have year, month & day.  Like I said earlier, please post separate question on SO, as it might help other users too.