# MongoDB aggregate result in the table format not in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

Hi I have used aggregation in Mongo similar to the one shown in the below link 
[MongoDB Return the count of documents for each day for the last one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516514/mongodb-return-the-count-of-documents-for-each-day-for-the-last-one-month)

I am getting the output as

```
/* 0 */    
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "2014-03-17",   
            "count" : 1
        },   
        {
            "_id" : "2014-03-15",  
            "count" : 9
        }        
    ],  
    "ok" : 1  
}
```

I need the result to be displayed in a table format so that I want to save this two columns in an excel sheet for future reference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb is a document oriented data base, so you need to write a small code to do the job for you. Or google to get the code one guy already write like the one on the question [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)
and adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command is an array, and cannot currently be returned otherwise. In JavaScript, you iterate an array to do what you want with the underlying result in a manner similar to this:

```js
var data = db.collection.aggregate([ /* your aggregation */ ]);

data.result.forEach(function(doc) {

    // do something with `doc`

});
```

Other languages will have similar handling or possibly even another type to handle the aggregate result.

In future releases, the results of aggregate will be a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which you iterate just like a standard cursor from find.