# MongoDB: Count documents created, for each day in the past X days, using _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking to gather sign up stats about users on my website--a signup count by date for the past X days via the mongo shell. The results could look something like:

```
Dec 7, 2019: 100
Dec 6, 2019: 150
Dec 5, 2019: 150
...
```

The documents do not have any `created_at` property, but there is an `_id` property which I believe can be used to achieve this goal?

If that can help be more clear, the equivalent in MySQL would be something like `SELECT count(id) FROM Users WHERE created_at > timestamp_X_days_ago GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY DESC created_at`

The name of the collection is `Users`.

I tried many queries, and the one I believe to be the closest with is `db.Users.find({ "_id" : {$lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}}).count()`, if only `_id` I figured out how to cast a date on `_id`.

Mongo 3.6

Comment: see this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516514/mongodb-return-the-count-of-documents-for-each-day-for-the-last-one-month

Comment: Doesn't help, I don't have any other date fields besides what's available in `_id`

Comment: what is the value of `_id`?

Comment: @krishnaPrasad it's an `ObjectID`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572607/find-all-documents-within-last-n-days this question is asked before.

Comment: I do not have a `date` field. Only `_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `_id` field is of type [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html), the following query prints the counts by day, in descending order.

The initial match stage will filter documents by "last X days". For example, to process only the past 10 days documents from today, get the `past_x_days` in milliseconds and use it in the query:

```
var past_x_days = 10 * 86400000; // where 86400000 is millis per day (24*60*60*1000)

db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { 
              $gt: [ { $toDate: "$_id" },  { $toDate: { $subtract: [ ISODate(), past_x_days ] } } ]  
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { dateYMD: { 
             $dateFromParts : {
                 year: { $year: "$_id" }, 
                 month: { $month: "$_id" }, 
                 day: { $dayOfMonth: "$_id" }
             }
         } }, 
         count: { $sum: 1 } 
       } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { "_id.dateYMD" : -1 } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          count: 1, 
          dateDMY: { $dateToString: { date: "$_id.dateYMD", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } } 
      } 
  }
] )
```

The output will look like this:

```
{ "count" : 2, "dateDMY" : "09-12-2019" }
{ "count" : 3, "dateDMY" : "01-12-2019" }
```

---

**NOTE:** The above query works with MongoDB version 4.0. The query is modified to work with version 3.6:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          oid_date: { $dateToParts: { date: "$_id" } }, 
          dt_diff: { $subtract: [ ISODate(), past_x_days ] }  
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          oid_dt_ymd: { 
              $dateFromParts: { 
                  year : "$oid_date.year", 
                  month : "$oid_date.month", 
                  day: "$oid_date.day" 
              } 
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { 
              $gt: [ "$oid_dt_ymd",  "$dt_diff"  ]  
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$oid_dt_ymd", 
          count: { $sum: 1 } 
       } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { "_id" : -1 } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          count: 1, 
          dateDMY: { $dateToString: { date: "$_id", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } } 
      } 
  }
])
```

The following are the `ObjectId`s are input (shown here with their corresponding *date* values).

```
ObjectId(), Dec 10 2019
ObjectId(), Dec 10 2019
ObjectId("5c6b8f57f3558c2685b0d4e3"), Feb 19 2019
ObjectId("5c6b95a7f3558c2685b0d4e4"), Feb 19 2019
ObjectId("5c6b95a7f3558c2685b0d4e5"), Feb 19 2019
ObjectId("5dd525c60fd48753f98ea39b"), Nov 20 2019
ObjectId("5dd525c60fd48753f98ea39c"), Nov 20 2019
ObjectId("5dd525c60fd48753f98ea3a1"), Nov 20 2019
ObjectId("5dd60eaeae3321b020320583"), Nov 21 2019
```

And, the variable `past_x_days = 30 * 86400000`. The query returns:

```
{ "count" : 2, "dateDMY" : "10-12-2019" }
{ "count" : 1, "dateDMY" : "21-11-2019" }
{ "count" : 3, "dateDMY" : "20-11-2019" }
```

Comment: Thank you. We're using Mongo 3, so `$toDate` does not work. Checking right now for an alternative in Mongo 3.

Comment: Is it 3.0, or 3.2 or 3.4, or 3.6?

Comment: It is MongoDB 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You could use below aggregation query in mongo shell for efficient search. First perform the match followed by transformation to date for grouping.

```
var lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() -7);
var lastWeekObjectId = ObjectId.fromDate(lastWeek);


db.Users.aggregate(
{$match:{_id:{$gt:lastWeekObjectId}}},
{$addFields:{_id:0,roundDate:{$dateFromParts:{
     year:{$year:"$_id"},
     month:{$month:"$_id"},
     day:{$dayOfMonth:"$_id"}
}}}},
{$sortByCount:{$dateToString:{date:"$roundDate",format:"%m-%d-%Y"}}}
)
```

Comment: liked the `$sortByCount` stage, never noticed it existed... 

Answer (score 0):

Since mongo ObjectId holds a timestamp inside it, you can use this method to create new ObjectIds with the timestamp you want to compare to as boundaries, lower and upper:

```js
db.Users.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        _id: {
          $gt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2019-08-28T22:55:00Z')) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000"),
          $lt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2019-11-28T22:56:00Z')) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        date: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$_id'}}
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$date",
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        _id: 1
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

just change the dates to the desired dates you would like to query on..

So the match query filter by dates upon the _id of the object, then when we convert the ObjectIds we got to string, group by that day string, count, and sort :)